# zipkin examples not on Github

Tags: zipkin

Does anybody know where the zipking examples are located ? 
https://twitter.github.io/zipkin/Quickstart.html#super-quickstart

In the following I can read:

```
 ./bin/sbt "zipkin-example/run -zipkin.storage.anormdb.install=true -genSampleTraces=true"
```

I have found the zipking-example on Maven Central only. Not on Github.
[1.2.1-rc24](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.zipkin/zipkin-example/1.2.1-rc24)

It is still a bug in the documentation?

[Documentation mentions zipkin-example which doesn't exist](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/683)

Comment: Same here, i cant find any info as well

Answer (score 1):

It is a very long time ago, but it looks like it was moved here:

http://zipkin.io/pages/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Found multiple language examples at [github](https://github.com/openzipkin?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=example).
If you need basic setup steps: https://zipkin.io/
Integrated zipkin with spring boot 2 and mysql 
[Steps](https://github.com/dineshbhagat/mac-configurations/blob/master/apm/zipkin.md)
[example](https://github.com/dineshbhagat/Spring-boot-JPA-Two-Level-Cache)
Here is sample 
[image: rest+mysql+hibernate]